# $PATH variable is not read

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, path

I tried to install MacPorts. I added the following line to my `.zshrc` :

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin/port:$PATH
```

then when I type the `port` command I get this :

```
sudo: port: command not found
```

But when I try to use MacPorts by calling it directly from its file, it works :

```
$ /opt/local/bin/port
MacPorts 2.3.4
Entering interactive mode... ("help" for help, "quit" to quit)
[Users/tom] >
```

When I type this command `echo $PATH` this is what I get :

```
/opt/local/bin/port:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

What's wrong how to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

P.S.: I got the same problem when I tried to install git with Homebrew. It only works when I write the whole path (`/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.9.3/bin/git`) otherwise, despite trying to set the $PATH variable correctly, it uses an older version of git (that was already installed on my computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a 'path' to the PATH variable, not a file. In other words, you need to add the path to the directory that contains the executable, not the path to the executable.
So instead of:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin/port:$PATH
```

do this:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH
```

After you have modified the .zshrc file you need to reload the file by sourcing it or opening a new shell for the setting to take effect.

On a side note, zsh has a nice [alternative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919/6207268) for appending environmental variables. Instead of the statement above, you can do:

```
export PATH+=('/opt/local/bin/')
```

To help debug the issue, you can modify the PATH and other environmental variables directly on the command line just to confirm you have the syntax / path correct; these settings won't persist and only apply to current shell. Once you have the syntax worked out properly you can then add them to the .zshrc file.